# I can not uninstall chromium browser

Tags: uninstall, chromium

This browser crashes my entire system on a regular basis and absolutely has to be removed.

It does not appear in Software Center.

Running

```
sudo apt remove chromium-browser
```

tells me that it is not installed.

Yet it is sitting right here, totally on my system.

I was fairly sure I installed this through the Software Center but see nothing of Chromium under "installed," under any subheading.  Searching it out actually offers a second installation.

Next I tried using

```
sudo apt remove chromium-browser
```

but am told

```
Package 'chromium-browser' is not installed, so not removed.
```

Running the code you asked me to run outputs:

```
$ type chromium-browser
bash: type: chromium-browser: not found
```

I even tried using a Debian command I can not recall which ended with `-r chromium` though I am positive it was not installed that way.

Sorry for failing to edit properly, think I read you right this time.

Comment: Can you remember how did you install it? Please [edit] your question to add the output of the command `type chromium-browser`. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: What did you try so far other than `apt remove`? What about the answers in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/327023/cant-remove-a-package-not-installed-so-not-removed ?

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  The question you linked me to was regarding a zip file and I didn't find it helpful in this particular situation, unless I misunderstood (likely.)

Comment: Thank you for the update. Can you even launch Chromium? How do you do it? It doesn’t look like the system has any idea about it. If it’s a desktop shortcut, please paste the contents of the `*.desktop` file into your question. _“I even tried using a Debian command I can not recall which ended with "-r chromium"…”_ Probably `dpkg -r`? However, if it were installed using dpkg, APT would know about it.

Comment: Actually RoVo your linked question got me thinking, how they could still launch from terminal... I tried to do that and was told it was not installed.  Then I remembered I could edit the menu items, so I looked at where the launcher command went, and it was indeed in the snap folder.
So I did snap help, and then snap remove chromium.... it actually worked.  It's gone, not sure why it was overlooked by the Software Center.
Melebius and RoVo I hope helping people is making your lives better, be well!!

Comment: @adam Glad you got it sorted! You can post an answer, which will help anyone else who has the same issue. (Yes, you can answer your own question.)

Answer (score 12):

I see what you speak about. I had an issue like this: I installed Chromium from software center and could not uninstall it. The thing is that it was a snap package (don't ask me why) so you can't remove it with apt or dkpg
The solution to your problem is

```
sudo snap remove chromium
```